# Смена картинки по нечетному клику

Tags: javascript, html

Никак не могу понять как сделать смену картинки по нечетному клику, когда 1 раз кликаешь, то она меняется, 2 раз - не меняется, 3 раз - меняется и тд

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Обмен двух изображений</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  <!--//
    function chpict ()
    { var d=document
      var l=d.pm1.src
      d.pm1.src=d.pm2.src
      d.pm2.src=l
    }
  //-->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>Обмен двух изображений</h3>
  <img src="m1.gif" name=pm1 width=100>
  <img src="m2.gif" name=pm2 width=100>
  <form name="form1">
    <input type="button" value="Обменять" onClick="chpict()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Обмен двух изображений</title>
      <script language="JavaScript">
      <!--//
        var x;
        function chpict ()
        { 
          if(x){ x=false; return; }
          x=1;
          
          var d=document
          var l=d.pm1.src
          d.pm1.src=d.pm2.src
          d.pm2.src=l
        }
      //-->
      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <h3>Обмен двух изображений</h3>
      <img src="http://yandex.ru/favicon.ico" name=pm1 width=100>
      <img src="http://google.ru/favicon.ico" name=pm2 width=100>
      <form name="form1">
        <input type="button" value="Обменять" onClick="chpict()">
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ожидалось что-то такое ?

```js
document.getElementById('changeBtn').addEventListener('click', chpict);

var counter = 0;

function chpict() {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
  if (counter % 2 === 0) return;

  var l = document.pm1.src
  document.pm1.src = document.pm2.src
  document.pm2.src = l
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" name="pm1" width="100">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar6.png" name="pm2" width="100">
<form name="form1">
  <input type="button" value="Обменять" id="changeBtn">
</form>
```